# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() produces partial answer after a LIKE constraint in query

Tags: mysql, group-concat, sql-like

```
select b.book_id,isbn,title,description,book_count,group_concat(concat_ws(' ',a.firstname,a.middlename,a.lastname)) as authors 
from book b, author a, author_book ab 
where b.book_id = ab.book_id and a.author_id = ab.author_id 
and (a.firstname like '%abc%') group by isbn;
```

The above code produces,

```
1001 | 1234567890123 | C Programming | Good book for beginners |         10 | abcd
```

but the correct answer is of multiple authors as, (including efgh, ijkl authors)

```
1001 | 1234567890123 | C Programming | Good book for beginners |         10 | abcd, efgh, ijkl
1002 | 1234567890111 | Java | Good book for Java Programmers |          5 | xyz, uvw
...
...
```

which is achieved before without using LIKE constraint as,

```
select b.book_id,isbn,title,description,book_count,group_concat(concat_ws(' ',a.firstname,a.middlename,a.lastname)) as authors 
from book b, author a, author_book ab 
where b.book_id = ab.book_id and a.author_id = ab.author_id group by isbn;
```

How to achieve the expected output?

Comment: What is your expected output here ? You are getting exact results based on your SQLs. Ofcource you will see author 'abcd' if you use `and (a.firstname like '%abc%') `

Comment: I want all Book Info with all Authors Name where one of the Author is LIKE ???. Here I'm getting, of course, Book Info with the Author LIKE ???, not all Authors. How to do that?

Comment: Stop using commas between tables in the from clause, this will enable you to use explicit join syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other authors are removed because your constraint on author names apply even after you have used them to select which books you want.

Use your current author filter to return a list of book ids, and then use that as a subquery `WHERE bookId IN (SELECT ...)` to filter which books you want, and join again with author_book and author to get all authors of selected books.

Try something like this:

```
select  b.book_id,isbn,title,description,book_count,
 group_concat(concat_ws(' ',a.firstname,a.middlename,a.lastname)) as authors 
from book b, author a, author_book ab 
where 
 b.book_id = ab.book_id
 and a.author_id = ab.author_id 
 and b.book_id IN (
  SELECT ab.book_id 
  from author a, author_book ab 
  where a.author_id = ab.author_id  and (a.firstname like '%abc%')
)
group by isbn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your join table by twice, once to filter down by author, and then the second time to list all authors for the related books; and do this with just a single select clause.

nb: I assume `book_count` comes from the books table.

```
SELECT
      b.book_id
    , b.isbn
    , b.title
    , b.description
    , b.book_count
    , group_concat(concat_ws(' ', a2.firstname, a2.middlename, a2.lastname)) AS authors
FROM author AS a1
      INNER JOIN author_book AS ab ON a1.author_id = ab.author_id
      INNER JOIN book AS b ON b.book_id = ab.book_id
      INNER JOIN author AS a2 ON a2.author_id = ab.author_id
WHERE a1.lastname LIKE 'a%'
GROUP BY
      b.book_id
    , b.isbn
    , b.title
    , b.description
    , b.book_count
;
```

1. Please note you should stop using commas in between table names in
   the from clause which helps you to adopt explicit join syntax.
2. Additionally you should always (no exceptions) refer to every column
       using the relevant table or alias as a prefix.
3. Always list all non-aggregating columns in the group by clause. (MySQL has a "lazy syntax" that can accept just a single column - but it can fail depending on server settings.)

**IF** the `book_count` is actually calculated then:

```
SELECT
      b.book_id
    , b.isbn
    , b.title
    , b.description
    , COUNT(DISTINCT b.book_id) AS book_count
    , group_concat(concat_ws(' ', a2.firstname, a2.middlename, a2.lastname)) AS authors
FROM author AS a1
      INNER JOIN author_book AS ab ON a1.author_id = ab.author_id
      INNER JOIN book AS b ON b.book_id = ab.book_id
      INNER JOIN author AS a2 ON a2.author_id = ab.author_id
WHERE a1.lastname LIKE 'a%'
GROUP BY
      b.book_id
    , b.isbn
    , b.title
    , b.description
;
```

Comment: @UsedByAlready Thanks for the detailed explanation and your effort :)